# Wired Xbox Controller

Tags: 17.04, xbox-360

I've a Xbox Controller and I would like use it on Ubuntu 17.04 with **4.10.0-26-generic** kernel, but when it is connected by usb the controller start and never stop to blinking. If I use the **xboxdrv** what I got is a: *the controller is not found*

Any help?